# Facebook FQL returns "An unknown error occurred" when querying certain URLs

Tags: facebook, api, url, facebook-fql

I've suddenly started getting errors with error code 1 and "An unknown error occurred" when using FQL to query the share stats on a particular URL. This only started happening last week at approximately 2013-01-11 02:43:02 +0000 according to my records.

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN('http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=331975235')
```

Here's the URL I'm using to make the query:
http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=SELECT%20url%2C%20normalized_url%2C%20share_count%2C%20like_count%2C%20comment_count%2C%20total_count%2C%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20IN%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fphobos.apple.com%2FWebObjects%2FMZStore.woa%2Fwa%2FviewSoftware%3Fid%3D331975235%27%29

Which returns the following JSON results:

```
{

    "error_code": 1,
    "error_msg": "An unknown error occurred",
    "request_args": [
        {
            "key": "method",
            "value": "fql.query"
        },
        {
            "key": "format",
            "value": "json"
        },
        {
            "key": "query",
            "value": "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN('http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=331975235')"
        }
    ]

}
```

Normally, I would query several URLs at once, but in this case I narrowed down the problem to this particular URL that is causing the error in a batch.

Any ideas what could be causing this problem? I am assuming this is something internal on the Facebook side since it was working fine until last week. Additionally, the Facebook Platform Bugs tool (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) seems to not be working and it's sending me back to the developers main page.

Comment: The url mentioned in your questions seems to work now (has been a year since then). But I have the issue for some other urls, so it still seems to happen occasional.

Answer (score 0):

1. This query works now so the error is not reproducible

`[{"url":"http:\/\/phobos.apple.com\/WebObjects\/MZStore.woa\/wa\/viewSoftware?id=331975235","normalized_url":"http:\/\/phobos.apple.com\/WebObjects\/MZStore.woa\/wa\/viewSoftware?id=331975235","share_count":6389,"like_count":3383,"comment_count":262,"total_count":10034,"click_count":0}]`

2. The Bugs tool works as well

In the future file a bug to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs